# Android- customize built-in Component?

Tags: android, components

Let's say I create an intent to view a Google map like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.ACTION_VIEW");
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
intent.addCategory(android.intent.category.LAUNCHER);
intent.setData("Your Google My Map URL HERE");
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there any way to customize this `MapsActivity` component, or just get a handle in it to control/query it at all, or would I have to start from scratch to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to customize this MapsActivity component, or just get a handle in it to control/query it at all, or would I have to start from scratch to do this?

No. You have no right to hack into other apps, any more than they have the right to hack into yours. Use [`MapView`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html).

BTW, your example code there is scary. Never reference third-party apps by component name, as your code will break if that app refactors its code. Never add the `LAUNCHER` category to an `Intent` unless you are actually a launcher (e.g., a home screen). And bear in mind that this recipe is neither documented nor supported by Google.

Comment: Ok, I figured not, I just wasn't really sure what a "component" is or what I could do with it. And I got that example code from an answer to a previous SO question, heh.

Comment: @Rob Lourens: In Android-ese, a "component" is an activity, service, content provider, or broadcast receiver -- basically, the main things you see as child elements of `<application>` in the manifest. Also, sorry for the harsh tone in my answer.